# How to use iTunes Connect Transporter

Tags: app-store-connect

Is there anyone that can explain to someone that doesn't know how to use Terminal what are the commands to use Transporter for iTunes Connect?
I tryed to follow the guide but with no results....
These are my steps till now:

I put this command in terminal:

```
export TRANSPORTER_HOME=`xcode-select --print-path`/../
Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin
```

and my terminal change like this:

```
~ myname$ Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin
```

so I guess with this now I am in the transporter folder...
Now I want to etrieve my app’s current metadata Using Lookup Mode, and I tryed with this command:

```
$ iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u [myname@gmail.com] -p [mypassword] -vendor_id [id999999999] -
destination [Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin]
```

but I get this:

```
$ iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u [myname@gmail.com] -p [mypassword] -vendor_id [id999999999] -
-bash: Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin$: No such file or directory
```

I assume I'm writing the destination in a wrong way....
So how should I write that command?
And also... when I will have to upload my edited file... what shoud I put?
Thanks a lot for any help with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by putting the export command into a single line.

```
export TRANSPORTER_HOME=`xcode-select --print-path`/../Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/bin
```

Then you have to use the full path to the iTMSTransporter Binary. You can use the variable you just defined for this.

```
"$TRANSPORTER_HOME/iTMSTransporter" -m lookupMetadata -u ... -vendor_id ... -destination ~/myapp
```

1. The destination is the directory where the app data will be put. `~` means your user directory. So if your username is blue `~/myapp` means `/Users/blue/myapp`.
   **Don't** use Xcodes directory for this.
2. I would recommend to **NOT** specify your password with the -p parameter. You don't want your password to appear in bash_history. If you don't specify the passwort you will be asked for it.
3. Again. Make sure that this is in one line. You must not spread the command over more than one line. Unfortunately if you copy and paste from the pdf document you get a multi line command that won't work.

I suggest to open a text editor, paste the command from the pdf into the text editor and format the command so it is on a single line.

---

Then go to https://bugreport.apple.com and file a bug about the crappy documentation of iTMSTransporter

Comment: It worked... thanks a lot... I received a file and opening it I found a xml file inside... there I found nothing.... just my name and some other strings... I thought there I would have found all the metadata of my apps... like descriptions and keywords in all the languages... did I misunderstood the utility of this file?